# Error reading repository for QGIS Python Plugin does not contain metadata

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to load HERE icon library by adding git repo following `https://github.com/cedricr/here-icons-qgis`. The configuration was setup as shown in the image, which results in error stating it doesn't contain plugin metadata.

[image]

I altered the proxy settings to default following the instructions in error but that did not fix the issue. What is the solution to this error?

[image]

Comment: The HERE repository is not a QGIS plugin repository. It's a QGIS resource repository. Install the QGIS resource sharing plugin and add the HERE repository as stated in https://qgis-contribution.github.io/QGIS-ResourceSharing/usage/adding-repository.html "Use `HERE Icon Library` as Name and `https://github.com/cedricr/here-icons-qgis.git` as URL".

Comment: Yes that worked. I installed the QGIS resource sharing plugin and followed the guide. You can post this as the answer.